# Cross domain $.getJSON not firing the success function

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, getjson

This has me really confused. I'm sending a cross domain request that I know for *certain* that is getting through and returning successfully, but the success function does not get fired. I'm not seeing any alert...

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://xxxx.appspot.com?callback=?', function(json) { 
    //console.log(json);
    alert ('text');
  });
```

I have several indications that the request is successfull:

1. I see on the server
2. I see the response code and body in the network tab
3. When I tried to return a malformed JSON I do get an error.

But in no case I'm getting the alert in the success function

Tried it on several pages, using different versions of jQuery.

UPDATE: so I enabled the headers, and still exactly the same result. the alert is not firing.

this is the header from the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,SOAPserver,SOAPaction,Method,Accept,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 12:30:02 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 36
```

Comment: can you share your json that has been returned in response.

Comment: I just saw your update with the response header. Please have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As you clearly saw it was a cross-domain request, I suppose you know at least a little [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ?

In short, if you didn't set [the appropriate CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control) on the `appspot.com` server, there is no reason for the browser to allow the script to analyze the result. The good news is that in almost any server-side language, [it's very easy to add the relevant headers](http://enable-cors.org/). Of course that means you can change the server (or what is seen by the browser as the server, it might be a proxy).

---

**EDIT :**

I notice just now the `callback=?` in the URL you call. This means that you're calling the service in JSONP, not JSON (an obsolete solution for cross-domain problems). As it didn't work with the callback syntax and the response header contains `application/json`, you might try to see if it handles plain json. Try without `?callback=?` at the end of your URL.

Comment: I removed the parameter, and still the same result. the alert is not firing

Answer (score 0):

When talking about CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) it's all about headers.

It's really important your request headers and your answer headers are correct or it won't work.

If your request headers aren't correct the request will be killed merciless by the server.
If the answer headers aren't correct the answer will be ignored by the browser client.

In the answer you should find the following headers subset:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers

All the origins,methods and headers used by the request must be allowed on the server answer or it will be ignored.

For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE;
Access-Control-Allow-Headers Origin,SOAPserver,SOAPaction,Method,Accept,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type;
```

Without more infos I cannot be more usefull :)

Comment: I added these headers, and still the same problem

Comment: Could you share the request headers too ?
Have you already tried using $.ajax instead of $.getJSON?

On my experience I used $.ajax and the only problems I met were on the request/answer headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as well

`Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600`

Also, check the `Access-Control-Request-Method` in the browser request.